# d3.js collision detection speed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection, force-layout

I'm using the following d3.js example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231307. I want to be able to remove the animation and create her again. To do this (the part of destroy) I used just deleted the canvas element:

```
(elem=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

It works fine, but if I create the animation and remove it several times in a row, the animation becomes very slow for a period of time. After a while the animation (some seconds) it returns to the normal speed.

Is this normal because I'm working with many points (200) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the problem occurs?

Comment: I don't see any animation like that on that page.